# What is IP networking used for? Also does the application layer include the actual software?

Tags: ip, osi

I have read and learnt the fundamentals about the OSI model and its layers but just wondering is there a difference between the OSI model and IP networking or is it covered by OSI model?

Bit confused with the terminology than anything.

Also my final question actual software say a browser like chrome, is that considered part of the application layer in the OSI model or are the HTTP and other functions served by the layer only included. I am going with the latter option hence the word 'served'. Just want to know in case I get asked in a test to draw some sort of diagram...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the OSI model, there is the [Internet protocol suite model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite).  The OSI model would place IP networking at layer 3, the network layer.

A web browser is going to have components of the transport layer and all layer above it as they include TCP/port numbers functionality, http session, encryption, ECMA/Javascripting, etc.